# Writing to allocated char buffer

Tags: c, char

I have following code:

```
framingStatus compressToFrame(char* inputBuffer, size_t inputBufferLength, char* frame, size_t* frameLength)
{
    dword crc32 = GetMaskedCrc(inputBuffer,inputBufferLength);
    size_t length = snappy_max_compressed_length(inputBufferLength);
    char* compressed = (char*)malloc(length);
    snappy_status status = snappy_compress(inputBuffer,inputBufferLength,compressed,&length);
    if( status!=SNAPPY_OK )
        return FS_ERROR;
    frame[0] = 0x00; // Typ ramki skompresowany
    frame[1] = length&0xff;
    frame[2] = (length&0xff00)>>8;
    frame[3] = (length&0xff00)>>16;
    frame[4] = crc32&0xff;
    frame[5] = (crc32&0xff00)>>8;
    frame[6] = (crc32&0xff0000)>>16;
    frame[7] = (crc32&0xff000000)>>24;
    frame[8] = '\0'; // Pomoc dla strcat

    strcat(frame,compressed);
    *frameLength = length+8;
    free(compressed);

    return FS_OK;
}
```

Before calling this function I allocate memory for buffer named frame. All is ok, but assign instructions `frame[x] = ...` don't seem to write anything to buffer called `frame` and `strcat` concatenate `compressed` data to empty buffer without header I need.

Why assign instructions `frame[x] = ...` etc. don't give any result?

[EDIT:]
Can you suggest what function I have to use if I want to concatenate frame header with compressed data?

[EDIT2:]
Code presented below works just fine.

```
framingStatus compressToFrame(char* inputBuffer, size_t inputBufferLength, char* frame, size_t* frameLength)
{
    dword crc32 = GetMaskedCrc(inputBuffer,inputBufferLength);
    size_t length = snappy_max_compressed_length(inputBufferLength);
    char* compressed = (char*)malloc(length);
    snappy_status status = snappy_compress(inputBuffer,inputBufferLength,compressed,&length);
    if( status!=SNAPPY_OK )
        return FS_ERROR;
    frame[0] = 0x00; // Typ ramki skompresowany
    frame[1] = length;
    frame[2] = length >> 8;
    frame[3] = length >> 16;
    frame[4] = crc32;
    frame[5] = crc32 >>8;
    frame[6] = crc32 >>16;
    frame[7] = crc32 >>24;

    memcpy(&frame[8],compressed,length);
    *frameLength = length+8;
    free(compressed);

  return FS_OK;
}
```

Comment: Isn't frame a char (8 bit) array? You're assigning there dword...

Comment: `strcat` is for strings, not general binary bytes. Because `frame` first byte is zero, `strcat` will copy `compressed` starting at `frame[0]` and will stop copying when it sees a zero in `compressed`. See `memcpy`.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Without casting I have an error in VS2008.

Comment: If you're getting an error without the cast on malloc you're almost certainly compiling as C++ not C

Comment: You're filling in 9 bytes of data in frame, but mark the frame length as 8 bytes longer. That might be putting the start of a frame on top of the null in the previous frame.

Comment: @Phil Perry: You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat` is for strings, not general binary bytes. Because `frame` first byte is zero, `strcat` will copy `compressed` starting at `frame[0]` and will stop copying when it sees a zero in `compressed`.

Try `memcpy` instead.

```
memcpy(&frame[8], compressed, length);
```

Also, since the length of `frame` is passed as an argument, you might want to be checking the total length you are copying to `frame` to make sure there's no illegal overwrite in that case.

Comment: After this instruction I have empty frame,

Comment: @CppMonster Did you remove your `strcat`? And where and how are you checking the contents of `frame`?

Comment: Yes, I'm checking it with VS2008 debugger and cout instruction and it gives the same results frame is empty.

Comment: @CppMonster Did you check the contents of `compressed` right before the `memcpy`? Also check the value of `length`. `memcpy` should work as you need (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm) and `strcat` definitely is the wrong function to use.

Comment: When I saw your answer I was sure that it's solution, but something it's wrong or maybe it's something wrong with rest of code. Yes, buffer named compressed contains correct data, length variable is not zero too.

Comment: @CppMonster When you test with `cout`, the same principle applies. `cout` stops at a NUL byte, it encounters, which is the very first character in your frame.

Comment: Debugger don't shows data in frame, but when I wrote: for(int i=0;i<frameLength;++i)cout<<frame[i]; there are my compressed data with header. It's ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
frame[0] = 0x00;
```

which is the same as

```
frame[0] = '\0';
```

No matter what you add after the first character, `frame` becomes a `0` length string.

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, you use binary data and not text strings. Therefore, [`strcat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) function is inappropriate here, use [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) instead.

Furthermore, you should use `unsigned char` instead of plain `char`.
Additionally, you don't need to mask the values before shifting

```
frame[2] = (length&0xff00)>>8;
```

could be just

```
frame[2] = length >> 8;
```

And in this case, it is even buggy

```
frame[3] = (length&0xff00)>>16;
```

Same here

```
frame[5] = crc32 >> 8;
frame[6] = crc32 >> 16;
frame[7] = crc32 >> 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
frame[0] = 0x00;
```

will make the first character as end of string character therefore your string `frame` is empty.

```
frame[0] = 0x00;
```

is same as writing,

```
frame[0] = '\0';
```